# VPS host can't send email to Google and Yahoo Mail

Tags: email, centos, vps, email-server

I got a new VPS setup and I'm wondering why I can't send emails to yahoo and gmail. Here's the error in /var/log/maillog:

00:43:00 mylamp sendmail[32507]: o45Gh0nc032505: to=, ctladdr= (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120405, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.79.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Could be your IP got black-listed by a previous owner of your VPS's IP.  Common for an un-managed VPS to be compromised by a spammer or other blackhat activity in the wild.

Edit: Also, make sure your reverse DNS (rDNS) is set up properly, as big SMTP servers will need this to verify you are who you say you are.

Comment: THat pretty much sums it up. Use something like http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to check whether your server is OK or the IP is burned ;)